# subscripting a specific line from python's csv reader?

Tags: python, file-io, csv

i'd like to be able to access specific lines of a csv file through the csv reader.  For example, the fourth line.  Is there a way to do this with python's csv reader module?

Answer (score 4):

You just have to parse all the CSV file, and then use normal sequencing indexing.

Otherwise, you can do something like this

```
def my_filter(csv_file, lines):
   for line_number, line in enumerate(csv_file):
       if line_number in lines:
          yield line

my_file = open("file.csv")
my_reader = csv.reader(my_filter(my_file, (3,)))
```

Note that you can't avoid parsing the whole file, in a way or in another, because the lines are of variable lenght. The line count only advances when a '\n' is found, and it has to be found in a character by character basis.

Also, this filter won't work if you happen to have newline characters inside quotes in the csv file -- probably you are just better off parsing the whole file to a list, and retrieving the indexes from there, anyway:

```
my_file = open("file.csv")
my_reader = csv.reader(my_file)
my_line = list(my_reader)[3]
```

**update**
Most important: if you need random access to information which is far too large to fit in memory, just consider dumping it to a SQL database instead. It will spare one reinventing a lot of wheels.

Comment: for sure.  the file is just far too large to read the whole thing into memory at once.  i plan on accessing all of the lines, but also need to jump around the file and have to avoid loading the whole thing at once.

Comment: SO, the filter solution will help you - (as far as you don't have \n's inside literal values). I fyou need out of order access, the filter solution can be used to create a list like in the last example.