# csv.reader() or enumerate to read specific row in file without buffering the entire file?

Tags: python, csv, enumerate

I understand enumerate is better to use when it is needed to read a specific line from a large file, because it uses `next()`, can the same be done with `csv.reader()`?

**Edit:** the file in question is a CSV file

Comment: Do you want to read each line of your file ?

Comment: No, I want to get to the i th line quickly, using the least possible memory

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713181/how-to-find-specific-row-in-python-csv-module

Comment: @NikosTavoularis How can i avoid reading the whole file in at once though?

Comment: I dunno if you can avoid this, probably someone else may answer this, but with a quick search I found this old post where the the guy who provides the answer says that you cannot avoid it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215347/subscripting-a-specific-line-from-pythons-csv-reader

Comment: @NikosTavoularis Thanks a lot!   I do believe enumerate reads the file line by line until the desired line is found, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081836/reading-specific-lines-only-python) , so i guess that's the only way